# drag and drop listitem of a listview to another listview's listitem

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, drag-and-drop, expandablelistview

[image]

As shown in screenshot,I have listing of folders and associated albums.I have used expandable listview for that listing.
I have another list besides it which shows images.
When I click on any album,the second listview shows images of that particular album.

Now,I want to move image from existing ablum to another album.and I want to drag and drop desired image to another album to perform this functionality.

I would like to have your suggestions to solve the task !!

Comment: Have you got any solution of this ?

Comment: @NileshVerma: I have no complete solution but [this](https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview) might be helpful

Comment: may this help you in future http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2011/10/drag-and-drop-honeycombics.html. thnx for ur attention.

Comment: @NileshVerma: you can post some of the code and detail as answer so that I can accept it and reward you.

Answer (score 0):

@Mehul I guess you can use simple drag drop listener [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html) and [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html#DesignDragOperation) provided by google and on Drag ended you can add the path to the imageview in the desired album and remove from the current album and refresh your adapter and listview . If you want more slick animation, you can try ObjectAnimator class instead of drag and drop.